# PHP generate random percentages

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's a quick way to generate a `x` number of random percentages that sum up to 100%?

I've tried writing this function, however more times than not the 100% gets used up in the first 2 or 3 iterations and the rest are just 0%, and I'd like to keep all of the percentages above 0.

```
function randomPercentages($x) {

    $percent = 100;
    $return = array();

    for($i=1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
        $temp = mt_rand(1, $percent);
        $return[] = $temp;
        $percent -= $temp;
    }

    return $return;

}
print_r(randomPercentages(7));
```

Comment: yes, there is, but if you're limiting the individual percentages, then they're not really random anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your function to reach always 100 % with at least 1 % for each value (but the last values are often very low and the tendency increases with the number of percentages to generate):

```
function randomPercentages($x) {
    $percent = 100;
    $return = array();
    for($i=1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
        if($i < $x) {
            $temp = mt_rand(1, ($percent-($x-$i)));
        } else {
            $temp = $percent;
        }
        $return[] = $temp;
        $percent -= $temp;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

And here is a rewritten and tested function with the excellent idea and code by Felk (but zero values are possible):

```
function randomPercentagesFelk($x) {
    $temp[] = 0;
    for($i=1; $i<$x; $i++) {
        $temp[] = mt_rand(1, 99);
    }
    $temp[] = 100;
    sort($temp);
    $percentages = [];
    for($i=1; $i<count($temp); $i++) {
        $percentages[] = $temp[$i] - $temp[$i-1];
    }
    return $percentages;
}
```

I have rewritten it again "to keep all of the percentages above 0" (it's working with up to 98 percentages - beyond that zeros are allowed). This is faster than I expected: for 98 percentages it takes about 0.01 - 0.04 seconds in my testing environment:

```
function randomPercentagesFelkZero($x) {
    $temp[] = 0;
    for($i=1; $i<$x; $i++) {
        $new = mt_rand(1, 99);
        if($i<98) {
            while(in_array($new,$temp)) {
                $new = mt_rand(1, 99);
            }
        }
        $temp[] = $new;
    }
    $temp[] = 100;
    sort($temp);
    $percentages = [];
    for($i=1; $i<count($temp); $i++) {
        $percentages[] = $temp[$i] - $temp[$i-1];
    }
    return $percentages;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Generate a bunch of floats between 0 and 1. (or 0 and 100 if you wanna work with percentages right away)

Step 2: Sort them.

EDIT: Step 2 1/2: Add 0 and 1 to begin and end of list.

Step 3: Iterate over them. The differences between the current and previous ones  are your random percentages.

Example:

```
0.23, 0.65, 0.77

0.23 - 0.00 = 23%
0.65 - 0.23 = 42%
0.77 - 0.65 = 12%
1.00 - 0.77 = 23%
             ----
             100%
```

Some untested code:

```
$num = 5;
$temp = [0.0];
for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) $temp[] = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
sort($temp);
$temp[] = 1.0;

$percentages = [];
for ($i=1; $i<count($temp); $i++) $percentages[] = $temp[$i] - $temp[$i-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//One way to code Felk's solution :

function randomPercentages($x){
        $seeds = Array();
        for($i=0; $i < $x - 1; $i++){
                $seeds[] = rand(0,100);
        }
        sort($seeds);
        $results = [];
        for($i=0; $i < $x - 1; $i++){
                $last = $i == 0 ? 0 : $seeds[$i-1];
                $results[] = $seeds[$i] - $last;
        }
        $results[] = 100 - $seeds[$x-2];
        return $results;
}

print_r(randomPercentages(7));
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 28
    [6] => 25
)
```

Comment: Why limit the random numbers to be between 5 and 95?

Comment: Good question. I think I didn't want the function to return 100, but it doesn't matter as the array is sorted...